# Why is prefixing column names with the table name a convention?

Tags: sql, database-design, naming-conventions

I have seen this convention in many databases, but it is redundant. A few answers say it is to reduce confusion during complex joins, but this isn't a sufficient reason. If you are making complex joins, make aliases.

Do joins really represent such a common task that we should make standard tasks like selects, inserts, and updates redundant?

Why is prefixing column names with the table name a convention?

Comment: I would ask on dba.stackexchange.com

Comment: It's the least ambiguous and most clear.  BTW, I prefix even when using aliases and I *always* use 1 or 2-letter aliases.

Comment: I'm not sure it is a convention.  Either way this question seems subjective.  Voting to close.

Comment: Even while coding front-end its simpler to refer to the columns and not get confused, if such a convention is used.

Comment: @mellamokb For the table OrderLineItemPackErrorMails, I could use `olipem` instead of just `em`. Expecially when my query involves other ErrorMail tables. ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think there is actually a convention of prefixing column names with the table name.

As Philippe Grondier details, the 'proper' approach to data modelling is to first create a dictionary of data element names. Following the international standard [ISO 11179](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_element_name) guidelines:

`[Object] [Qualifier] Property RepresentationTerm`

you end up with data elements that are fully qualified. Here the qualifier elements `Object`, `Qualifier` and sometimes `Property` are in combination what you consider to be the 'prefix'.

On implementation of the data model in SQL, the table name can provide the context and leads the designer to drop the qualifying terms from the column name. I think this is convention you prefer.**

In other words, in the convention you are questioning it is not that the table name has been prefixed to the column name, rather it is that the qualifying terms have been retained.

---

** whether or not yours or any other is a good convention is subjective and Stackoverflow is not the place for such discussion. However, I will mention in passing that retaining qualification terms does have a practical benefits (as well as being theoretically sound) e.g. consider that SQL's `NATURAL JOIN` lends itself to columns that are named consistently throughout the schema.

Comment: +1: I think you're right by saying that we should better question the convention where the qualifying terms are dropped at the table level

Comment: Does this convention has anything to do with the fact that first PC database software, back in the 80's, could only accept 8 letters for table names and 10 letters for field names?

Answer (score 3):

It is true that such "developped column names" methods are widely used for column naming where, for example, Tbl_Person will have an id_Person primary key column, and a personName text column.

Though it might seem at first quite painfull to write 'developped' column names like "id_Person", "personName", "personAdress", etc, everything gets clearer when you have to write SELECT's on multiple tables, which is something that happens each time you open a form or a report.

**There is also a theoretical/historical dimension to this "developped column names" method**. First relational databases theories and methods (like MERISE) were proposing, as a first step, to build the so-called "**data dictionary**", ie the list of all data to be manipulated by the app\database.

This dictionary has to be established even before any "Entity-Relation" model is proposed. **data names/descriptions have then to be fully developped**, this **to avoid confusion between 'similar' data entries**, like, for example "companyName" and "personName".

Thus, **the "developped column names" convention reflects the fact** that, at the data level, **similar columns** (such as a Company.name and a Person.name columns) **are not as equivalent as they seem to be**. Though they both look like being here to hold a name, one of them is made to hold a company name, while the other is made to hold a person's name!

This convention can then be considered as a way to reflect the exact meaning of each of the database's column, or to reflect **the exact meaning of each entry in the data dictionary**.

Answer (score 2):

I've never seen the full table name prefixed, but usually at least an abbreviation. And you're exactly right, it's for simplicity in joins and the like. It's easier to write ur_id all the time than it is to write id sometimes and userrights.id other times, for example. It's not that uncommon to need to access more than one table at a time.

Answer (score 2):

Join is part of a select, so that comparison doesn't hold.

That aside, I don't think you should prefix the field with the table name, except for primary keys. I like to give every table a surrogate key, which I rather name after the table. So the table 'Orders' will get an 'OrderId' PK. An order line will have a foreign key OrderId to point to the order. That way, the field names are the same across tables, and you can tell by the name, which data it presents. You could name the field just 'Id' in all tables, but you do have to read the alias to see which ID you mean. Some queries I wrote are over 400 lines. You don't want to rely on table aliases alone. A little context in the fieldname itself does help.

Comment: "Join is part of a select" -- I'd say it was part of the `FROM` clause, actually. Also note that other constructs involve a (logical) join without using the `JOIN` keyword e.g. the search condition in a `MERGE`.

Comment: I tried to answer to the remark: "Do joins really represent such a common task that we should make standard tasks like selects, inserts, and updates redundant", which almost suggests that a JOIN could be a replacement for a SELECT statement, which is of course not the case. But I must admit, my reply wasn't that clear either. :)

Answer (score 2):

It's not a convention; some people do it, some people don't. More often I see an ID column prefixed with the table name, but no other columns. Some (all?) DBs also allow prefixing with the table name in queries, but it's neither required, nor part of the actual column name.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what others said, it is also makes things simpler in the presence of identifying relationships (a.k.a. identifying FOREIGN KEYs).

An identifying relationship "migrates" the parent's primary key into a part of child's primary key. Prefix ensures there will be no collision and you won't need to rename the migrated fields, even when there are multiple levels of identifying relationships. For example:

```
PARENT:
    PARENT_NAME      PK

CHILD:
    PARENT_NAME      PK, FK referencing PARENT
    CHILD_NAME       PK

GRANDCHILD:
    PARENT_NAME      PK, FK referencing CHILD
    CHILD_NAME       PK, FK referencing CHILD
    GRANDCHILD_NAME  PK
```

Keeping the same name throughout the whole data model avoids any confusion as to what the field means and where it came from.

On the other hand, prefixing can take a toll on readability, so I usually take a compromise: prefix primary key fields but leave other fields unprefixed.

Answer (score 1):

I dislike such naming conventions. It encourages sloth, specifically the use of unqualified references in queries. Use an alias for each table in your query and qualify each column reference with the appropriate alias.

The only such naming convention I like has to do with primary/foreign keys:

- I like to name primary keys something clever, like `id`.
- I like to name prefix the names of foreign key columns with the name of the table containing the primary key.

It makes for much more legible SQL, IMHO. An example:

```
   create table foo
   (
     id int not null primary key ,
     ...
   )

   create table bar
   (
     id int not null primary key ,
     foo_id int not null foreign key references foo (id) ,
     ...
   )

   select *
   from foo foo
   join bar bar on bar.foo_id = foo.id
```

This scheme falls down, of course, when you get to compound keys. But I like it. YMMV.

Answer (score 0):

### A special case

As others have pointed out there is no impirative reason to do so. Ambiguity can easily be fought with a complete `schema.table.col` convention.

There is one practicle reason though and that when your physical environment uses a MySQL-dialect as DML. This language type conveniently supports a `USING` in a JOIN
`clause` which makes for easier writing and reading statements.

Compare

With a relation `t1` with PK `t1_ID` and `t2` with a PK `t2_ID` and FK `t1_ID`

```
SELECT t1.a, t2.b
FROM t1
INNER JOIN t2 USING(t1_ID)
```

and
With a relation `t1` with PK `ID` and `t2` with a PK `ID` and FK `t1_ID`

```
SELECT t1.a, t2.b
FROM t1
INNER JOIN t2 on t1.ID = t2.t1_ID
```

Which appears small a difference but with longer table names version one offers slightly better readable and hence less error prone code.